Ctrl+J breaks my textures
What should I do to join parts of the shoes that I made?
After CTRL J my meshes break. I read I can use boolean modifier but I don't really know what setting I should use. I'll be pleased if you help me out.



I don't see why you mention booleans here, it's not related to materials. We don't know how each of the objects you try to join are modeled and how are their materials, we're in the blind here so it's a bit hard to give an accurate answer without it being just lucky guesses. It would be nice to [edit] your question to add more details, and why not also share your file so that we can check it ourselves.

Normally when you join objects, Blender should keep the material assignation areas so it shouldn't be an issue. What could be an issue is modifiers uses in the objects you joined. as Blender also tries to keep those, but you might have not built all your objects the same way, and thus some of them have modifiers that "break" things once applied to all the now-joined object. I do notice lots of z-fighting in the second screenshot, indicating something like a mirror modifier got applied where it shouldn't. So there's definitely not "just" a material issue there.

That being said, for what reason or purpose do you try to join your objects in the first place? There aren't many cases where that is needed, so it might not even worth the trouble to be honest.

Do the UV maps for the object mesh data blocks have different names?

All meshes in Blender are composed by at least two entities: a container and its content.
When you perform a Ctrl J operation between Container A and Container B, both Contents A and B will be placed into a single container (last selected, "Active" object, the one with light orange outline, lets say Container A).
Problems arise because the containers can have their own properties, modifiers and parent relations, so in example Content B can change because previously it had properties coming from Container B, and now it gets different properties from the new Container A).
To solve, check both containers before joining: select container B (Shoes in your example), press Alt P > Clear Parent and keep transformations, press Ctrl A > Apply all Transform, go to modifiers and apply them all (Ctrl A hovering on the modifier, starting from the topmost one), unless there's an identical modifier on Container A (the body, in your example), in which case you can leave the modifier in place.
Check also constraints and apply them if present.
Check also if content data share some elements with the same name (expecially UV Maps and Vertex groups), and change their names if needed, so to avoid names conflicts.
Now Ctrl J will join as expected (in your case, probably some mirror modifiers need to be applied before joining).
Booleans are meant to be used if you need a final "waterthight" single mesh, and it's probably a bad idea in your case.


Thanks, it was helpful
